# Integration with two different answer

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

In the below question I am getting two different answers.
$$\int \dfrac{\cos4x-1}{\cot x-\tan x}dx$$
Solution:
$$\dfrac{\cos4x-1}{\cot x-\tan x}$$
$$\dfrac{-2\sin^2 2x(\sin x\cos x)}{(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)}$$
$$\dfrac{-2\sin x\cos x(\sin^2 2x)}{(\cos 2x)}$$
$$\dfrac{-\sin 2x(1-\cos^22x)}{\cos 2x}$$
Therefore
$$\int \dfrac{-\sin 2x(1-\cos^2 2x)}{\cos 2x}dx$$
Case1
$$\int \dfrac{-\sin 2x(1-\cos^2 2x)}{\cos 2x}dx = 
-\int \dfrac{\sin 2x(1-\cos^2 2x)}{\cos 2x}dx$$
Putting $t=\cos 2x$ and differentiating w.r.t $x$
we get,
$dt=-\sin 2x(2)dx$ i.e.$-\dfrac{dt}{2}=\sin 2xdx$
Thus, $$-\int\dfrac{-dt(1-t²)}{2t}
      =\dfrac{1}{2}\int \dfrac{dt}{t}-\dfrac{1}{2}\int tdt$$
$$=\dfrac{\ln|\cos 2x|}{2}-\dfrac{\cos^2 2x}{4}+C$$
Case 2:
$$\int \dfrac{-\sin2x(1-\cos^22x)}{\cos2x}dx
=-\int\dfrac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}-\sin2x\cos2xdx$$
$$=-\int\tan2xdx+\dfrac{1}{2}\int2\sin 2x\cos 2xdx
=-\dfrac{-\ln|\cos2x|}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\int\sin4xdx$$
$$=\dfrac{\ln|\cos2x|}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(-\cos4x)}{4}
=\dfrac{\ln|\cos 2x|}{2}-\dfrac{1}{8}(\cos4x)+c$$
Why am I getting two different answer and where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: `this is for programming code`. To type formulas we have MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results differ by a constant... they are both correct, or both incorrect.

Comment: sir can you give me a little more insight on it

Comment: The constant $c$ in case 1 and 2 is an arbitrary constant... If you call them $c_1$ and $c_2$ maybe it will become clear.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping

Comment: By applying formula for Cos2x  you can get the other answer but constant can be different because in your case you are dealing with indefinite integral.